# Implementing insert() on a container with move semantics when rvalue does not implement move

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, move

I'm trying to implement a container that provides insert methods with both copy and move semantics.

The implementation is something like this:

```
template <typename T> class Buffer {
    // lots of stuff ommitted here
    ...

    // copy semantics
    Buffer<T>::Iterator push(const T& item) {
        Buffer::Iterator head = push();
        *head = item;
        return head;
    }

    // move semantics
    Buffer<T>::Iterator push(T&& item) {
        Buffer::Iterator head = push();
        *head = std::move(item);
        return head;
    }
}
```

This works fine if type T (the type to be pushed into the buffer) implements a move assignment operator. However, I get a compiler error if I try to push instances of something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int a) : m_bar(a) {}
    int m_bar;
    Foo& operator=(Foo& other) {
        this.m_bar = other.m_bar;
    }
}
```

If I try to compile `buffer.push(Foo(42));` I get a compiler error for the `push(T&& item)`-method on the line that reads `*head = std::move(item);`. The error is that there is no viable overload for `operator=` that accepts an rvalue - which is correct, there isn't one. There is only an assignment operator that accepts lvalues.

But since I can't make sure that every object ever to be stored in my container will have a properly implemented move assignment operator I need to make sure that this case is handled correctly. What's more, std::vector handles this without a problem. When an object implements move assignment `push_back` will move it, if not it will copy it. Regardless if it is an rvalue or not. In fact if I put my problematic `Foo` rvalue that caused the error earlier into a std::vector it works like it should.

So what am I missing? How can my container implement move semantics and still support rvalue references for objects that don't implement move assignment?

Comment: Aren't you actually default constructing each element before you insert it? This is really not what you want to do.

Comment: You mean with the `head = push()`? That doesn't really default construct anything. `push()` without arguments just moves some markers around to "make space" for a new element. It's not obvious from this example though, sorry for that. All it really does is return an iterator to the new (uninitialized) head. That element potentially contains data from an older element that occupied the position before but other than that it's "empty". I thought about nulling empty slots in the buffer but I didn't want to take the performance hit since I didn't see what I would gain from it.

Comment: @sseeland: what `*head` does then? does it evaluate to `Foo&`? was this element default-constructed? you should not operate on uninitialized element, even if it is just lhs of copy-assignment. instead, you should use `new(memory_area) Foo(arguments);` syntax, see [std::raw_storage_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/raw_storage_iterator/) as a reference implementation

Comment: @piotr-s: Hm, yeah actually. It evaluates to Foo&. Never thought about that. Does that mean when I reference `(*head)` (which returns a reference to an uninitialized memory position like `m_buffer[index]`, does that automatically default construct an element at that instance and then copy assign the new element to it? If so: yikes! Good you brought it up, I'll look into it.

Comment: @sseeland: no, it does not default-construct an instance in such case. the problem is, this is a raw memory, so the lhs object is in *unknown state*, which leads to UB. that being said, imagine that `operator=` first deallocates a pointer that the instance stores, can you see the problem? if not, see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34c3d04dca3c2448)

Comment: it's the *placement-new* operator that guarantees that constructor is called while instantiating object at given memory address, don't use uninitialized memory as if it was an object. in your case it should be `new (m_buffer[index]) Foo(other)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing/assuming wrong is the *incorrect* signature of a copy-assignment operator:

```
Foo& operator=(Foo& other);
```

which takes a *non-const lvalue* reference to the `other` instance. This prevents a move from falling back into a regular copy if there is no user-provided assignment operator taking an rvalue reference (that is, an rvalue can be bound by a **const** lvalue reference), so it should be:

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other);
//             ~~~~^
```

> *Then why it works with `std::vector<Foo>` then ?*

The `buffer.push_back(Foo(42));` statement utilizes a copy constructor, not an assignment operator. This works, since `Foo` has an *implicitly generated* copy-constructor of the following signature:

```
Foo(const Foo&);
```

which works for both lvalues and rvalues ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d983422e25166f5f)).

What you are trying to do:

```
*head = std::move(item);
```

is to use an assignment operator. Since you have declared one on your own, a compiler can't generate implicitly the one taking a const lvalue reference, and it can't also use the user-declared one taking a non-const lvalue reference, which results in the error you see.

Consider using allocators or the *placement-new* operator in your `push` operations, using the `item` parameter as the argument for the constructor of `Foo`, instead of using copy-assignment and move-assignment operators.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I actually used that incorrect copy assignment constructor on purpose to construct a sentinel class for a unit test. I'll see whether I can make the test work with the correct signature and whether I can make your suggestions work in my container.